# Execute js which came from an external domain into a new tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

My very first question here.

I'm on a chrome extension which should be able to get the entire DOM of a page (from the current tab) and reinject it in a new tab. So far everything works perfectly except about js files. Calls to files are correctly written in the DOM I inject in the new tab but it looks like they are not executed (and not even downloaded according to the "Source" tab in the Chrome's dev-tool).

Is there a permission I forgot or is the cause dealing with CSP ? If it's this second case, is there a way to get around the problem ?

Here's the manifest :

```
{
  "name": "CS DomReady Checker",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Get the DOM Ready",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "assets/img/icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": ["tabs", "<all_urls>", "webNavigation"],
  "icons": { 
    "128": "assets/img/icon-128.png" 
  }
}
```

popup.js :

```
//Sniff the DOM of the current tab
function domReadyChecker(noJs, displayBlock) {
  //Init error message container
  var messageContainer = document.getElementById('messageContainer');
  messageContainer.setAttribute("style","display:none;");

  //Select the active tab in the active chrome window
  chrome.tabs.query({active:true,currentWindow:true},function(tabArray){

    //Reload the page we want to sniff dom
    chrome.tabs.reload(tabArray[0].id,{bypassCache:true},function(){
      var domainName = extractDomain(tabArray[0].url);
      //Wait for the dom to be loaded
      chrome.webNavigation.onDOMContentLoaded.addListener(function(details){
        if (details.frameId === 0) {
          //Script injection into the page
          chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
            file: 'assets/js/getPagesSource.js'
          }, function() {
            // If you try and inject into an extensions page or the webstore/NTP you'll get an error
            if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
              messageContainer.setAttribute("style","display:block;");
              messageContainer.innerText = "Il y a eu une erreur d\'injection : \n" + chrome.runtime.lastError.message;
            }
            else {
              return false;
            }
          });
        }
      },{url: [{hostContains: domainName}]});
    });

  });

}

//Inject the DOM into a new tab
function injectDomInTab(tab, html, url) {
  //Send message to result.js
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {action:'injectHtml', source:html, hrefAttr:url}, function(resultResponse){
        if(resultResponse.response) {
          //Active the injected tab
          chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {selected:true});
        }
  });
}

//Extract the host name of an url
function extractDomain(url) {
    var domain;
    //find & remove protocol (http, ftp, etc.) and get domain
    if (url.indexOf("://") > -1) {
        domain = url.split('/')[2];
    }
    else {
        domain = url.split('/')[0];
    }
    //find & remove port number
    domain = domain.split(':')[0];
    return domain;
}

//Trigger the magic...
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  document.getElementById('sniffDom').onclick = domReadyChecker;
});

//Intercept message from getPagesSource.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender) {

  if (request.action == 'getSource') {
    var html = request.source;
    var url = request.url;

    //Create new tab
    chrome.tabs.create({active:false,url: chrome.extension.getURL('result.html')},function(Tab){
      //Wait for the tab to be created and inject to inject the dom
      chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo){
        if (tabId === Tab.id && changeInfo.status === "complete") {
          injectDomInTab(Tab, html, url);
        }
      });
    });

  }
});
```

getPageSource.js :

```
function DOMtoString(document_root) {
    var html = '<base href="'+window.location.href+'">',
        node = document_root.firstChild;
    while (node) {
        switch (node.nodeType) {
        case Node.ELEMENT_NODE:
            html += node.outerHTML;
            break;
        case Node.TEXT_NODE:
            html += node.nodeValue;
            break;
        case Node.CDATA_SECTION_NODE:
            html += '<![CDATA[' + node.nodeValue + ']]>';
            break;
        case Node.COMMENT_NODE:
            html += '<!--' + node.nodeValue + '-->';
            break;
        case Node.DOCUMENT_TYPE_NODE:
            // (X)HTML documents are identified by public identifiers
            html += "<!DOCTYPE " + node.name + (node.publicId ? ' PUBLIC "' + node.publicId + '"' : '') + (!node.publicId && node.systemId ? ' SYSTEM' : '') + (node.systemId ? ' "' + node.systemId + '"' : '') + '>\n';
            break;
        }
        node = node.nextSibling;
    }
    return html;
}
//Send message to popup.js
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    action: "getSource",
    source: DOMtoString(document),
    url: window.location.href
});
```

result.js

```
//Intercept message from popup.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse){
    if(request.action === 'injectHtml') {
        //Inject the sniffed dom into the new tab
        document.documentElement.innerHTML = request.source;

        sendResponse({response: true});
    }

});
```

On a random website i get two errors :

> Refused to load plugin data from
>   'http://www.youtube.com/v/08X0t9hcyl4&rel=0&fs=1&showsearch=0&showinfo=0'
>   because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "object-src 'self' blob: filesystem:".

and

> Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin
>   provided ('http://blog.wanken.com') does not match the recipient
>   window's origin
>   ('chrome-extension://fdkkfiefjneekgpgnlobbmdnmanoeolf').

Thank you for your help.

Comment: How are you reinjecting the html? Are you getting errors?

Comment: I added some details about the scripts and errors.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add your js files in "web_accessible_resources" like this:

```
{
 "name": "CS DomReady Checker",
 "version": "1.0",
 "manifest_version": 2,
 "description": "Get the DOM Ready",
 "browser_action": {
   "default_icon": "assets/img/icon.png",
   "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
 "permissions": ["tabs", "<all_urls>", "webNavigation"],
 "icons": { 
   "128": "assets/img/icon-128.png" 
  },
 "web_accessible_resources": [ "js/youjsfile.js ", "js/another.js"]
}
```

Comment: The thing is my scripts do the job. Here I need scripts that are called by the website run in my new tab. I don't know if i'm really clear ... :/